# pytorch 1D Dropout leads to unstable learning

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, dropout

I'm implementing an Inception-like CNN in pytorch.  After the blocks of convolution layers, I have three fully-connected linear layers followed by a sigmoid activation to give me my final regression output.  I'm testing the effects of dropout layers in this network, but it's giving me some unexpected results.

Here is the code:

```
class MyInception(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, verbose=False):
        super(MyInception, self).__init__()
        self.v = verbose
        ic=in_channels; oc=16
        self.inceptionBlock1 = InceptionBlock(in_channels=ic, out_channels=oc, maxpool=False, verbose=verbose) 
        self.inceptionBlock2 = InceptionBlock(in_channels=oc * 6, out_channels=oc, maxpool=False, verbose=verbose) 
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)

        self.regressor = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(oc * 6 * 35 * 35, 1024, bias=True),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False),  # <--- Dropout 1
            nn.Linear(1024, 128, bias=True),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False),  # <--- Dropout 2
            nn.Linear(128, 1, bias=True),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.inceptionBlock1(x)
        x = self.inceptionBlock2(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = self.regressor(x)
        return x


def train(epochs=10, dot_every=25):
    running = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Epoch','Round','TrainLoss','TestLoss','LearningRate'])
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        train_losses = []
        model.train()
        counter = 0

        for images, targets in train_loader:
            images = images.to(device)
            targets = targets.to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = loss_fn(torch.flatten(outputs), targets)
            train_losses.append( loss.item() )
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            counter += 1
            if counter % dot_every == 0: 
                print(".",  end='.', flush=True)
                test_loss = test()
            else:
                test_loss = -1.
            lr = np.squeeze(scheduler.get_lr())
            running = running.append(pd.Series([epoch, counter, loss.item(), test_loss, lr], index=running.columns), ignore_index=True)

        test_loss = test()
        train_loss = np.mean(np.asarray(train_losses))
        running = running.append(pd.Series([epoch, counter, train_loss, test_loss, lr], index=running.columns), ignore_index=True)
        print("")
        print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}, Train Loss: {np.round(train_loss,4)}, Test Loss: {np.round(test_loss, 4)}, Learning Rate: {np.format_float_scientific(lr, precision=4)}")
    return running


def test():
    model.eval()
    test_losses = []
    for i, (images,targets) in enumerate(test_loader):
        images = images.to(device)
        targets = targets.to(device)
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = loss_fn(torch.flatten(outputs), targets)
        test_losses.append( loss.item() )

    mean_loss = np.mean(np.asarray(test_losses))
    return mean_loss

# instantiate the model
model = MyInception(in_channels=4, verbose=False).to(device)
# define the optimizer and loss function
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay=0.0001)
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()

# run it
results = train(epochs=10, dot_every=20)
```

Here is a plot of the MSE losses for the training data.  (red = no dropout, green = second dropout only, blue = first dropout only, purple = both dropouts)
Runs with dropout have big increases in losses at the epoch boundaries (dashed vertical lines), with the double dropout even having a big jump in loss at the start of epoch 10.

[image: MSE Loss on Training Data]

The important thing is the test loss.  That is much more stable and not too different between either condition after the 5th epoch, so maybe I shouldn't care. But I would like to understand what is going on.

[image: MSE Loss on Test Data]

Answer (score 2):

I cracked the case.  I realized that I flip model.train() to model.eval() in the test call without setting it back to train() after.  Since Dropout behaves differently in train and eval modes, adding in Dropout revealed the bug.